# self is not a keyword in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyword

I read that self is not a keyword in python, but why the following code outputs: (10, 10)???

One of my function use `selff` and other one use `self`.

I use python 2.7.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(selff, x=0, y=0):
        selff.x = x
        selff.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)

p1 = Point(10,10)
print p1
```

Comment: It should always be `self` for member variables.

Comment: Because it's first argument that python is secretly passing to those methods.  You could technically name it whatever you want, but the same object (a reference to itself) is always going to be put there.

Comment: @DylanLawrence It doesn't have to be `self` but the convention is strong with this one.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't think I've ever seen anyone call it anything else, it might technically be changeable, but incredibly inadvisable.